# Why classes like `list`, `str` starting from small letters and other has camel case fonting

Tags: python, class

In python some classes are starting from small letters like `list`, `filter`, `str` and some are starting with capital letters like `KeyError`, `OptionParser`, etc.

Is there any difference between these classes.

Comment: I think those whom considered as Python primitive data types (Including `str`, `list`, `dict`, etc.) are started with lowercase letters, and others are started with upper case letters.

Comment: Got It!!! Just read it is mentioned in PEP8 also.